# Resize image using imresize gives an error in octave

Tags: arrays, image, image-processing, multidimensional-array, octave

I'm trying to resize a **very small image** using Octave 5.2.0 but I'm not sure why it's giving an error when trying to resize it

The error happens with the line below:

```
img_unique_only = imresize(f2, [640, 480]); %reshape output of unique colors
```

- 

```
error: interp2: cubic requires at least 2 points in each dimension
error: called from
    interp2 at line 244 column 9
    imremap at line 65 column 19
    imresize at line 135 column 8
    test_small_resize_question at line 30 column 17 (the last line which is the imresize line)
```

Code Below:

```
pkg load image

f(:,:,1)=[0;0;0;0;127;128;128;128];

f(:,:,2)=[0;0;127;128;0;0;0;0];

f(:,:,3)=[127;128;0;0;0;0;127;128];
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------

[im_r im_c]=size(f);
size_min=min(im_r,im_c); %get minum size from row and col
f2=uint8(f)
imshow(f2)

img_unique_only = imresize(f2, [640, 480]); %reshape output of unique colors
```

Using `imshow(f2)` creates the image below

[image: img1]

The Line `img_unique_only = imresize(f2, [640, 480]); %reshape output of unique colors` won't resize it

Variables created:

[image: img2]

When using the line `img_unique_only = imresize(f2, [640, 480], "nearest"); %reshape output of unique colors`

Variables created:

[image: imgg]

I get a **gray scale** image instead of a **640x480 color image**

[image: img3]

Note: I'm also willing to try another way if better

Comment: You have an image that is 1 line. Cubic interpolation requires at least 2 values in each direction. You don't have them. Are you sure that its an image? people don't call arrays "images". You can try to use a different interpolation method, check `imresize` docs.

Comment: I added a uint8 to make sure its an image and did a `imshow(f2)` I updated the question with image

Comment: something being `uint8` does it not make it an image hehe. The only thing it makes it be an images is that you say that your matrix is an image. The error is clear, and I told you how to solve it: use a different interpolation technique than the default cubic

Comment: I guess I missing something because I tried `nearest, cubic, bilinear, bicubic, linear`  example: `img_unique_only = imresize(f2, [640, 480], "nearest");`   nearest produces an image but it's grey scale not color

Comment: what is `size(img_unique_only)` and `size(f2)` with nearest? The rest is obvious, you need at least 2 values to interpolate, and you don't have them in one of the directions

Comment: I updated the question to add the image created.  It's 640x480 but it's grey scale instead of color.  I'm glad you think it's obvious (I wish it was for me to hahah :-D)

Comment: I don't have octave installed, but you can alsways just use `interp2` instead (its just the same) or resize each color channel independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work around is to use `cat` Note: it creates a gradient of colors that aren't correct.

```
f(:,:,1)=[0;0;0;0;127;128;128;128];
f(:,:,2)=[0;0;127;128;0;0;0;0];
f(:,:,3)=[127;128;0;0;0;0;127;128];

height_wanted=640;
width_wanted=480;

repmat_rgb=cat(2,f,f); %add another column to array to get imresize to work
reshaped_output = imresize(repmat_rgb, [height_wanted, width_wanted],'cubic'); %reshape swatch to large output

imshow(reshaped_output);
```

[image: img]

**Update: July 19 2021**
**It's a bug in imresize for more info and workaround
[Matrix array to multidimensional RGB image array and using imresize to reshape image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68445353/matrix-array-to-multidimensional-rgb-image-array-and-using-imresize-to-reshape-i)**