# Matrix array to multidimensional RGB image array and using imresize to reshape image

Tags: arrays, image-processing, multidimensional-array, octave, rgb

I'm using **Octave 5.2** and can create a 640 x 480 x 3 image from an array of RGB values using `meshgrid` and `reshape` but is there a better way of doing this? (**code is below**)  I tried using `cat` and `imresize with nearest` but the array is 640x480 not 640x480x3 and it creates black squares due to the fact the array is not in a 640x480x3 format can this be worked around to get the colored bar image?.

```
f(:,:,1)=[255;0;0;0;0];
f(:,:,2)=[0;255;0;0;255];
f(:,:,3)=[0;0;255;0;2];

num_of_colors=numel(f(:,:,1));
img_resize_height=640
img_resize_height_tmp=round(img_resize_height/num_of_colors); %create the height wanted

%1) create size of array wanted 
[r_im_tmp_x r_im_tmp_y]=meshgrid((f(:,:,1)),1:img_resize_height_tmp)
[g_im_tmp_x g_im_tmp_y]=meshgrid((f(:,:,2)),1:img_resize_height_tmp);
[b_im_tmp_x b_im_tmp_y]=meshgrid((f(:,:,3)),1:img_resize_height_tmp);

%2) reshape grid to evenly space out colors (in one column)
r_resize_tmp=reshape(r_im_tmp_x,[1,numel(r_im_tmp_x)])';
g_resize_tmp=reshape(g_im_tmp_x,[1,numel(g_im_tmp_x)])';
b_resize_tmp=reshape(b_im_tmp_x,[1,numel(b_im_tmp_x)])';

%3 make array size wanted 480
img_resize_len=480;
r_resize_tmp2=repmat(r_resize_tmp,([1,img_resize_len]));
g_resize_tmp2=repmat(g_resize_tmp,([1,img_resize_len]));
b_resize_tmp2=repmat(b_resize_tmp,([1,img_resize_len]));

img_resize_rgb(:,:,1)=r_resize_tmp2;
img_resize_rgb(:,:,2)=g_resize_tmp2;
img_resize_rgb(:,:,3)=b_resize_tmp2;

figure(1);
imshow(img_resize_rgb);
```

The image it creates is **correct** there just seems like there may be a simpler / better way to code this.

[image: img1]

I tried using `imresize` command to do the same thing to improve the code. (see code below).

```
pkg load image

f(:,:,1)=[255;0;0;0;0];
f(:,:,2)=[0;255;0;0;255];
f(:,:,3)=[0;0;255;0;2];

height_wanted=640;
width_wanted=480;

repmat_rgb=cat(2,f,f); %add another column to array to get imresize to work
reshaped_output = imresize(repmat_rgb, [height_wanted, width_wanted],'nearest'); %reshape swatch to large output
imshow(reshaped_output);
```

The image created is **incorrect** and black and white (most likely due to the array being 640x480 instead of 640x480x3 (how can I fix this?)

[image: img2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in `imresize` implementation of Octave image package (in MATLAB the code is working).

When the input of `imresize` is RGB (3D matrix), the output should also be RGB (3D matrix).
In your example the output is Grayscale (2D matrix instead of 3D matrix).
It is a **bug in `imresize` implementation**!

---

The function is "open source", and we can debug it using the debugger.
Executing the code step by step (stepping into `imresize`) get us to the following piece of code:

```
  elseif (strcmpi (method, "nearest") && all ([int_row_scale int_col_scale]))
    ## we are matlab incompatible here on purpose. We can the stuff here in 2
    ## ways. With interp2 or by clever indexing. Indexing is much much faster
    ## than interp2 but they return different results (the way we are doing it
    ## at least). Matlab does the same as we are doing if the both columns and
    ## rows go the same direction but if they increase one and decrease the
    ## other, then they return the same as if we were using interp2. We are
    ## smarter and use indexing even in that case but then the results differ
    if (int_row_scale == 1)
      row_idx = (1:rows (im))(ones (1, scale_rows), :);
    elseif (int_row_scale == -1)
      row_idx = ceil (linspace (floor (1/(scale_rows * 2)) + 1, inRows, outRows));
    endif
    if (int_col_scale == 1)
      col_idx = (1:columns (im))(ones (scale_cols, 1), :);
    elseif (int_col_scale == -1)
      col_idx = ceil (linspace (floor (1/(scale_cols * 2)) + 1, inCols, outCols));
    endif
    im = im(row_idx, col_idx);
```

The bug is in the last line of the above part.

Instead of `im = im(row_idx, col_idx);` it should be:

```
im = im(row_idx, col_idx, :);
```

---

In case you don't want to edit the "[image package](https://octave.sourceforge.io/image/)" code, you may use the following workaround:
Resize each color channel and concatenate the resized channels.

Replace `reshaped_output = imresize(repmat_rgb, [height_wanted, width_wanted], 'nearest');` with:

```
out_r = imresize(repmat_rgb(:, :, 1), [height_wanted, width_wanted], 'nearest');
out_g = imresize(repmat_rgb(:, :, 2), [height_wanted, width_wanted], 'nearest');
out_b = imresize(repmat_rgb(:, :, 3), [height_wanted, width_wanted], 'nearest');
reshaped_output = cat(3, out_r, out_g, out_b);
```

---

Note:
The class of `f` is `double`, and the range of the values supposed to be [0, 1].
All values above `1` are clipped to `1` when using `imshow`.

You may initialize `f` to:

```
f(:,:,1)=[1;0;0;0;0];
f(:,:,2)=[0;1;0;0;1];
f(:,:,3)=[0;0;1;0;1];
```

Or cast to `uint8`:

```
f(:,:,1)=[255;0;0;0;0];
f(:,:,2)=[0;255;0;0;255];
f(:,:,3)=[0;0;255;0;255];
f = uint8(f);
```

Comment: Thanks!  that fixed it.  I filed a bug report

https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?60946